# Not possible to override command with CMD or Entrypoint

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-container, docker-entrypoint

I am executing the following command from the [postgres doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

> docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
> -d postgres

Now out of curiosity I run the following:

> docker run -it --name some-postgres -e
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres bash

and I don't end up with an interactive bash shell.
Also trying:

> docker run -it --name some-postgres --entrypoint bash -e
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres

does not work either.

How come I am not able to override the default command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is working properly, but since you are using the `-d` flag the container is being started in the background.
Remove that flag and you'll be in an interactive bash session:

```
docker run -it --name some-postgres --entrypoint bash -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```